# Hide Phonegap spash screen

Tags: javascript, cordova, screen, splash-screen

I've made an app using Phonegap build that i'm ready to release, the only problem is I want to get rid of the splash screen but don't know how to.
So is there any way to fix this?

/Johannes

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` should work, if you're on the latest version.

Comment: Doesn't look too bad http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen ;-)